# Executing promises in batches even if some failed

Tags: node.js, for-loop, promise

I am trying to create users in batches of 20. I have created the functions to do this and placed them all in an array "promises" with a counter.
When the counter reaches 20 or the total number of users has been uploaded, I execute all the promises in the array.
This works fine, until one of the functions returns an error, which breaks the entire code, even though it is in a loop for the total amount of users:

```
for (const user of usersjson.users) {
{functions}
if (promises.length == 20 || i == usersjson.users.length) {
                await Promise.allSettled(promises)
                .then((responses)=> {
                  for (const response of responses) {
                    if (response.value.status == 204) {
                      console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.request.path.substring(7)} was updated.`);
                    } else {
                      if (response.value.status == 201 && response.value.headers.location) {
                      console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.headers['location']} was created.`);
                      } else {
                        console.log(response.value.headers.location);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }).catch((err)=> {
                  console.log(err);
                });
                promises=[];
              }
            }
```

How can I make the loop continue even if one of the functions returns an error and the catch is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `Promise.allSettled()` and it will resolve when each Promise in an array resolves or rejects. The `Promise.allSettled()` itself will never reject. That means that you can just check if some of the Promises in an array has rejected after the `Promise.allSettled()` resolves and in that case handle it in your business logic. You can do it like this:

```
Promise.allSettled(promises).then((responses) => {
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    if (response.status === 'fulfilled') {
      // Promise resolved
    } else {
      // Promise rejected
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks!
So in effect, instead of going to the catch, it will handle the rejected promises with whatever I put in the ELSE section?

Comment: Yeah. You can handle it how you want.